# PyQt Custom Data Structure

Tags: python, data-structures, widget, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a simple `PyQt4` program that takes in 3 Particulars (Name,Gender & Address) whenever i clicked on OK button and save it as a binary file (3 particulars are hard coded in program for testing purpose). Then later will load that information back and display it in `QTableWidget`.

This is the layout of my program:

It has 2 scripts: **DContainer.py** and **Data_Main.py**

[image]

**Dcontainer.py**

```
import bisect
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, Name = None, Gender = None , Address = None ):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Gender = Gender
        self.Address = Address

class PersonContainer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__fname = QtCore.QString("mydatabase.mqb")
        self.__persons = []
        self.__personFromId = {}

    def __iter__(self):
        for pair in iter(self.__persons):
            yield pair[1]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__persons)

    def Clear(self):
        self.__persons = []
        self.__personFromId ={}

    def add(self,person):
        if id(person)in self.__personFromId:
            return False
        key = person.Name
        bisect.insort_left(self.__persons, [key,person])
        self.__personFromId[id(person)] = person
        return True

    def save(self):
        fh = QtCore.QFile(self.__fname)
        if not fh.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly):
            raise IOError , unicode(fh.errorString())
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(fh)
        for key, person in self.__persons:
            stream << person.Name << person.Gender << person.Address

    def load(self):
        fh = QtCore.QFile(self.__fname)
        if not fh.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            raise IOError , unicode(fh.errorString())
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(fh)
        while not stream.atEnd():
            Name = QtCore.QString()
            Gender = QtCore.QString()
            Address = QtCore.QString()
            stream >> Name >> Gender >> Address
        self.add(Person(Name,Gender,Address))
```

**Data_Main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui
import DContainer

class MainDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainDialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.InitGui()
        self.persons = DContainer.PersonContainer()
        self.Update()


    def InitGui(self):
        buttonbox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(buttonbox)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.connect(buttonbox.button(buttonbox.Ok), QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.OK)

    def OK(self):
        NewPerson = DContainer.Person(QtCore.QString('This is another test'),QtCore.QString('Male'),QtCore.QString('Strand Road'))
        self.persons.add(NewPerson)
        self.persons.save()
        self.Update()

    def Update(self):
        self.table.clear()
        self.persons.load()
        self.table.setRowCount(len(self.persons))
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)

        for row,person in enumerate(self.persons):
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(person.Name)
            self.table.setItem(row,0,item)


def Main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = MainDialog()
    dialog.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

My Problem is whenever i clicked on OK button, it create multiple table entries

**After second click**

[image: after 2nd click]

It should not create multiple table entries as i have used

```
if id(person)in self.__personFromId:
            return False
```

in my Add method in Dcontainer.py.

Rightfully, it should only show one item in the table unless i give the new person object with different name.

What is causing the problem?

Comment: The objects probably have unique ids as they are not actually the same objects. Appologies for the crap formatting in comments: >>> a = {'Hi': 1}
>>> b = {'Hi': 1}
>>> print id(a), id(b)
249688688 249688832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PersonContainer.add` method is called twice when you click the OK button:

1. Directly from the `MainDialog.OK` method
2. Indirectly from the `MainDialog.Update` method, with `self.persons.load()`

You can add an optional argument to the `Update` method to trigger the call to `load`:

```
def Update(self, load=False):
    self.table.clear()
    if load:
        self.persons.load()
```

And call this method with `load` set to `True` in the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(MainDialog,self).__init__(parent)
    self.InitGui()
    self.persons = DContainer.PersonContainer()
    self.Update(True)
```

By the way, the old style signal/slot is no longer supported with PyQt5. This is how to write in the new style:

```
    buttonbox.accepted.connect(self.OK)
    buttonbox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
```